# Button Click Won't display contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On button click. code suppose to submit the contents and display the contents. can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```js
 

  var currentDate = new Date()
 var day = currentDate.getDate()
 var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
 var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
 document.getElementById('date').innerHTML =("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>");

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btn_submit').click(function(){
  var descriptionO =$('#descriptionO').val();
  var PurchaseO = $('#PurchaseO').val;
  var total = $('#total');
  var notes = $('#notes');
 $.post('ajaxjs.php'),{postdescriptionO:descriptionO,postPurchaseO:PurchaseO,posttotal:total,postnotes:notes},

 $.ajax({
 type:'Post',
 url: 'index.php',
 data: $(this).serialize(),
 cache: false,
 success: function(result){
  $("display").html(result);
```

```css
$descriptionO=$_POST['descriptionO'];
$PurchaseO=$_POST['PurchaseO'];
$total=$_POST['total'];
$notes=$_POST['notes'];
```

When I click the button nothing happens. I have inspected the page and it is not throwing any error. When I click the button I suppose to receive content displayed on the same page.I am a beginner

Comment: 1) I don't believe `var Purchase Order` is valid, 2) you test for `$description0`, but your variable is `description`, your other vars in the `if` aren't right either, none of them should have a `$` looking at the code.

Comment: What is not working? Is the form is validating? or you are always getting "Please Fill All Fields"? You have a var Purchase Order which is wrong.

Comment: @NawedKhan form is not validating.

Comment: Assuming you are running the JS part in a browser, did you have a look at the developer console to see what errors are thrown?

Comment: the whole IF condition is malformed. What is empty() ? why there are $ marks? variable names don't match. else block has no opening { bracket.

Comment: Besides all the other issues people have mentioned you also haven't assigned anything to `dataString` which you are using in your ajax